# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin Google Maps in Jquery and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that is running on my Google Maps. But today started giving the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest can not load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-26.905, -49.05694 & sensor = true. Http://localhost:36452 Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The call of JQuery is this:

```
function alturaPonto(lat, lng, edt)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",            
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=" + lat + "," + lng + "&sensor=true",
    success: function (msg) {                    
        var retorno = msg.results[0].elevation;                    
        edt.val(retorno);
    }
  });                
}
```

Everything was ok, but now gives error.
The result below works, and is called by a button. After that, or if I click on the map to create a point on the map and take the lift does not work. Why the difference between the two returns if the call is the same?

```
Request URL:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-26.905,-49.05694&sensor=false
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
locations:-26.905,-49.05694
sensor:false
```

Not working

```
Request URL:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-26.899415168090034,-49.05200242996216&sensor=false
Request Headersview parsed
GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-26.899415168090034,-49.05200242996216&sensor=false HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:36452/Posicionador
Origin: http://localhost:36452
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
locations:-26.899415168090034,-49.05200242996216
sensor:false
```

How to resolve this directly in JQuery? 
tks